# How do I say "Why not both" in Mandarin?

Tags: translation, mandarin

Specifically, how would I say "Why not (choose) both?" or "Why not (do) both?"

Ex. "Do you want to go to the park or go watch a movie?" "Why not both?"

I tried to do some searching and found two possible answers:

> 1. 为什么不两者兼得?
> 2. 为什么不两样都做?

Can someone help verify if either are correct? If not, what's the most natural way of saying it?

Answer (score 3):

为什么不两者兼得? - this is more likely to appear in books or writing.

为什么不两样都做? - this sounds more natual.

If you choose to say the second one, you may want to change it a little bit by saying 为什么不两个地方都去？

But I would say 不如两个地方都去！as this sounds more energetic, simpler and positive.

Reference: Native speaker

Comment: Leaving out "两个地方" can also make it sound more like you're a native, although less proper/formal.

Answer (score 1):

"Why not both" is not an actual question that seek an answer, it is a rhetorical question (more like a statement or a suggestion) that pointing out the obvious solution. Therefore, I would translate " why not both" as 「兩樣都幹不就行了？」( wouldn't it be fine to just do both?)

If you want to translate it in a more literal way, you can say:「何不兩樣都做？」( why not do both?)

你为什不 sounds like a question seeking an answer, 何不 sounds like a rhetorical question more.

Answer (score 0):

I was told for 'Why don't you choose both?' you could say '你为什么不两个都选啊？‘

Answer (score 0):

两者兼得 can be used like this: 两个都去不就两者兼得了吗？

So the speaker needs to let people know the subject first. (What's 兩者's 兩 is about)

Personally, I will say: 不然两个都去（选）！／要不兩个都去（选）？／两个（选）都去也行啊／何不两个都去（选）？

If you use 为什么, it will sound more like asking why you are not doing something. Using 何不 can show the inviting tone.